# Using openID framework for authentication method in Openfire

Tags: java, authentication, openid, xmpp, openfire

We all know that openId has become such a popular method for user authentication, that's why i was thinking if Openfire chat server can use it as well. I know that openId communicate using http protocol while Openfire on XMPP , but i wanted to know If some how Openfire authorization module can be customized to use one of the openID java libraries for authentication (for a web browser based chat client). If possible how much effort it will take for someone experienced(not very experienced) with network programming in java?

P.S. I have also posted this in openfire community.

Comment: Hey, have you pursued this idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to fully customize openfire,
One way is to create account using openfire user service plugin and make your own authentication and message sending plugin. Openfire supports custom plugins
Fully customize openfire authentication module is second option, but I do not recommend it as it will be trouble in updating openfire.

It will likely take 3 - 4 weeks to develop such thing based on plugin.

Comment: Thanks,that was very helpful.I believe the 3-4 weeks will include the major debugging & testing as the developer and ready for demo.

Comment: How would you catch authentication in a plugin? IQs and Messages which could get handled would only be available after authentication. So developing authentication on them isn't possible. How can a Openfire plugin filter something else then an IQ or Message?